# In sage: from $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ to $(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^*$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, sagemath

In Sage `G=IntegerModRing(11^5-1)` gives me the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/161050\mathbb{Z}$. From here `U=G.unit_group()` gives me the group $(\mathbb{Z}/161050\mathbb{Z})^*\simeq\mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/3220\mathbb{Z}$ .

**Question:** how can I get **in Sage** the element in $\mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/3220\mathbb{Z}$ corresponding to $11\in\mathbb{Z}/161050\mathbb{Z}$?

There is a map from $(\mathbb{Z}/161050\mathbb{Z})^*$ to $\mathbb{Z}/161050\mathbb{Z}$: we can do `U.inject_variables()` to get variables `f0` and `f1` and then make `G(f0)` and `G(f1)` to get the corresponding elements of $\mathbb{Z}/161050\mathbb{Z}$. But `U(G(11))` responds an error.

Of course the number here a only example and I search a general method.

Comment: Since $11$ obviously is a unit (it is coprime to $161050$), we already have $11\in U(161050)$.

Comment: I know that, but I would like to get in Sage the corresponding element in `Zmod(161050).unit_group()`

Comment: I'm ok with that! My question is a purely Sage question: how can I get this element in Sage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`U(G(11).generalised_log())` does what you want. See the documentation for this method [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/finite_rings/sage/rings/finite_rings/integer_mod.html#sage.rings.finite_rings.integer_mod.IntegerMod_abstract.generalised_log).